# How to detect localNotification close button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios5

I want to code a close button of UIlocalNotification in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the Close button action.

After scheduling a **`LocalNotification`** it becomes a System event, so can only access the **view event**, calling the **`didReceiveLocalNotification()`** method.

The following example shows how to access the view event, as explained above:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```